# symfony multiple Entities in one Form issue that I do not understand

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, entity

started to work with symfony2. I like it so far. I tried myself on a multi entity form to figure out, if the form builder is usable for my needs.
So first of all my entities:

Customer entity

```
    namespace CustomerBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
        use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
        use UserBundle\Entity\Users;

        /**
         * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
         * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
         * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerRepository")
         */
        class Customer
        {
            /**
             * @var ContainerInterface
             */
            protected $container;
            /**
             * @ORM\Id
             * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
             */
            protected $Id;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="nickname", type="string", length=50, unique=true)
             */
            protected $NickName;
            /**
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CustomerBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="Customer")
             **/
            protected $Addresses;

            /**
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CustomerBundle\Entity\Mail", mappedBy="Customer")
             **/
            protected $Emails;
            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\Users")
             * @ORM\JoinTable(name="customers_mapping_users",
             *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
             *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
             *      )
             **/
            protected $Users;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="lead_type", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $LeadType;
            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\Users", fetch="EXTRA_LAZY")
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lead__owner_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
             */
            protected $LeadOwner;
            /**
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CustomerBundle\Entity\Note", mappedBy="Customer")
             **/
            protected $Notes;
            protected $Reminders;
            protected $SupportTickets;
            protected $Invoices;
            protected $Documents;
            /**
             * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\CustomerBundle\Entity\Todo", mappedBy="Customer")
             **/
            protected $Todos;

            /**
             * @return Todo[]
             */
            public function getTodos()
            {
                return $this->Todos;
            }

            /**
             * @param Todo $todo
             */
            public function addTodo(Todo $todo)
            {
                $this->Todos->add($todo);
            }

            /**
             * @param Todo $todo
             *
             * @return bool
             */
            public function hasTodo(Todo $todo=null)
            {
                return $this->Todos->contains($todo);
            }

            /**
             * @param Todo $todo
             *
             * @return $this
             */
            public function removeTodo(Todo $todo)
            {
                $this->Todos->removeElement($todo);

                return $this;
            }
}
```

My Address Entity

```
<?php

    namespace CustomerBundle\Entity;
        use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

        /**
         * @ORM\Table(name="customers_address")
         * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
         * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomerBundle\Entity\AddressRepository")
         */
        class Address
        {
            /**
             * @var ContainerInterface
             */
            protected $container;
            /**
             * @ORM\Id
             * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
             */
            protected $Id;
            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="Addresses")
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
             **/
            protected $Customer;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $FirstName;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $LastName;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="company_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $CompanyName;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="street1", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Street1;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="street2", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Street2;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="street3", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Street3;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="zipcode", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Zipcode;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $City;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Country;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Phone;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="fax", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $Fax;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="tax_id", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
             */
            protected $TaxId;
}
```

and last but not least

```
    namespace CustomerBundle\Entity;

    use HomeBundle\Traits\CreateTrait;
        use HomeBundle\Traits\serializeTrait;
        use HomeBundle\Traits\UpdateTrait;
        use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

        /**
         * @ORM\Table(name="customer_mail")
         * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
         * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CustomerBundle\Entity\MailRepository")
         */
        class Mail
        {
            /**
             * @var ContainerInterface
             */
            protected $container;
            /**
             * @ORM\Id
             * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
             * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
             */
            protected $Id;
            /**
             * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
             */
            protected $Email;
            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="Emails")
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
             **/
            protected $Customer;
}
```

According to http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html I added three Form Types:

Address:

```
        use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

        class AddressType extends AbstractType
        {
            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                $builder
                    ->add('FirstName','text',array('label'=>'firstname'))
                    ->add('LastName','text',array('label'=>'lastname'))
                    ->add('CompanyName','text',array('label'=>'company name'))
                    ->add('Street1','text',array('label'=>'street 1'))
                    ->add('Street2','text',array('label'=>'street 2'))
                    ->add('Street3','text',array('label'=>'street 3'))
                    ->add('Zipcode','text',array('label'=>'zip code'))
                    ->add('City','text',array('label'=>'city'))
                    ->add('Country','text',array('label'=>'country'))
                    ->add('Phone','text',array('label'=>'phone'))
                    ->add('Fax','text',array('label'=>'fax'))
                    ->add('TaxId','text',array('label'=>'taxid'));
            }
            public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
            {
                $resolver->setDefaults(
                    array(
                    'data_class' => 'CustomerBundle\Entity\Address',
                    )
                );
            }
            public function getName()
            {
                return 'address';
            }
        }
```

Mail:

```
        use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

        class MailType extends AbstractType
        {
            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                $builder
                    ->add('Email','email',array('label'=>'email'));
            }
            public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
            {
                $resolver->setDefaults(
                    array(
                    'data_class' => 'CustomerBundle\Entity\Mail',
                    )
                );
            }
            public function getName()
            {
                return 'mail';
            }
        }
```

and the customer as top level instance:

```
    <?php
        namespace CustomerBundle\Form\Type;

        use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
        use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
        use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

        class CustomerType extends AbstractType
        {
            public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
            {
                $builder
                    ->add('NickName','text',array('label'=>'customers nickname'))
                    ->add('address','collection',array('type'=>new AddressType()))
                    ->add('mail','collection',array('type'=>new MailType()));
            }
            public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
            {
                $resolver->setDefaults(
                    array(
                        'data_class' => 'CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer',
                    )
                );
            }
            public function getName()
            {
                return 'customer';
            }
        }
```

In the create action of My Controller I added this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/Customers/Create", name="crm_customers_create")
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $customer = new Customer();
    $address = new Address();
    $mail = new Mail();
    $customer->addAddress($address);
    $customer->addEmail($mail);
    $form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(),$customer);
    return array(
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
    );
}
```

and my Twig Template contains:

{% extends "HomeBundle:Core:base.html.twig" %}

```
    {% block title %}CustomerBundle:Customers:create{% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>{% trans %}create a new Customer{% endtrans %}</legend>
                {{ form_start(form) }}
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

So as soon as I cann the page I only get this output:

Expected argument of type "array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)", "boolean" given
        500 Internal Server Error - UnexpectedTypeException
        Stack Trace

```
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/ResizeFormListener.php at line 84  -
                    }
                    if (!is_array($data) && !($data instanceof \Traversable && $data instanceof \ArrayAccess)) {
                        throw new UnexpectedTypeException($data, 'array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)');
                    }
                    // First remove all rows
        at ResizeFormListener ->preSetData (object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))
        at call_user_func (array(object(ResizeFormListener), 'preSetData'), object(FormEvent), 'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))
        in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1826  +
        at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(array(object(ResizeFormListener), 'preSetData')), 'form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
        in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1759  +
        at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ImmutableEventDispatcher.php at line 43  +
        at ImmutableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 342  +
        at Form ->setData (false)
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataMapper/PropertyPathMapper.php at line 57  +
        at PropertyPathMapper ->mapDataToForms (object(Customer), object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 396  +
        at Form ->setData (object(Customer))
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php at line 488  +
        at Form ->initialize ()
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.php at line 226  +
        at FormBuilder ->getForm ()
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.php at line 39  +
        at FormFactory ->create (object(CustomerType), object(Customer), array())
        in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php at line 250  +
        at Controller ->createForm (object(CustomerType), object(Customer))
        in src/CustomerBundle/Controller/CustomersController.php at line 47  +
        at CustomersController ->createAction ()
        at call_user_func_array (array(object(CustomersController), 'createAction'), array())
        in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3109  +
        at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
        in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3071  +
        at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
        in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3222  +
        at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
        in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2444  +
        at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
        in web/app_dev.php at line 29  +
```

I don't know there the issue comes from as I can't see which of the entities causes the fault.
Everything looks fine so far.
I also tried to access only one of the form fields, but that leed to the same exception.
I appreceate any help with solving this issue.

Comment: The Entities are reduced in size so I don't bust the 10.000 Character Limit. I only removed getter and setters as well as add/remove handling from the entities. If needed I can add them as well

Comment: Just added one complet call for one of the array collections. the others are built similar to the others

Comment: properties `addresses` and `emails` in customer form do not match entity ones.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Didn't see that. Can you post your Comment as answer, so I can accept it. (Please) ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form field names must match entity property names. In `CustomerType` form fields `address` and `email` do not match `Customer` entity properties `Addresses` and `Emails`.